# Oracle APEX Cards Tooltip

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a classic report with cards. I want to display a value when the user mouseover any of the cards. How can I do that?

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44321:410:0:

Comment: I look fast and I think it's easy to integrate in apex. Instead of use CDN, i recomend to download the files and put in your workspace. https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

Answer (score 1):

One method might be to add a value to card modifiers column, then run a Dynamic Action after refresh of your region, that would execute the following JS (fire on initialisation).

The first jQuery selector is driven by your card modifier value - I used 'titleA'

```
$('.titleA a').attr('title','Help me');
```

This should modifer your generated HTML accordingly

[image]

Comment: This enables you to leave the subscribed template alone, but it's a little awkward having to add HTML post-render.

Answer (score 0):

There are three mouse related dynamic actions you can use without having to write any JavaScript:

Mouse Enter (mouseenter) - Fires once when the pointing device is moved into the triggering element.

Mouse Leave (mouseleave) - Fires once when the pointing device is moved away from the triggering element.

Mouse Move (mousemove) - Fires when the pointing device is moved while it is over the triggering element.

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmdb/managing-dynamic-actions.html#GUID-95E8C5A5-6A25-4786-BD7A-809C18F17D3B).